# angular ui-grid how to use onRegisterApi in gridOptions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a editable table with extra rows .columnDefs. I added a grid api to table to get alert when something was change:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
        //set gridApi on scope
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                alert('edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue);
            }
        });
    };
```

I don't know how to use it in columnDefs. I tried  `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {}`
But it isn't work. I have to get information what was changed in this sub rows.

Answer (score 2):

`$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) ...` won't work, because `onRegisterApi` is not a property of `columnDefs` - it belongs directly in `gridOptions`.

If you want to only watch changes for a particular row / column or some such combination, filter by their name(s) in the handler function.

Answer (score -1):

I dont see your problem, if you want to know what row, column changed , the code you have is right.

```
gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue){
        $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue ;
        console.log('edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue);
        $scope.$apply();
      });
```

The rowEntity is the data row which was modifier. ColDef is the exact column which was edited.

Try it again or explain more in your question.